# For loop for creating files having consecutive names

Tags: filenames, for

I want to create files like song1.mp3,song2.mp3,song3.mp3... in my home directory.How to create this using for loop?

Comment: Welcome to Unix Stackexchange! You can [take the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) first and the learn [How to Ask a good question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 4):

No `for` loop needed if they're consecutive numbers:

```
touch ~/song{1..20}.mp3
```

Answer (score 1):

DopeGhoti's answer is more succint, but if you're dead-set on a for loop,

```
for i in $(seq 1 5); do
    touch song${i}.mp3;
done;
```

Should do the trick.

`$(seq 1 5)` evaluates to `1 2 3 4 5`, and then the for-loop iterates over that sequence. Replace 1 and 5 with whatever values you need.